# Region of triple integral

Tags: integration

Let $S$ be the solid bounded by $x+z=2$, $z=0$, and $4y^2=x(2-z)$. It's very hard to me to visualize the shape of this region, can anyone please help me thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**GeoGebra** visualization ([www.geogebra.org](http://www.geogebra.org)):

[image]